# C++ not modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++

When I run this code, I get the an error saying `C.getRadius()` isn't modifiable lvalue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Circle {
        double x, y, r;
public:
        Circle (double a=1.0, double b=1.0, double c=1.0) { x=a; y=b; r=c; }
        ~Circle() {}
        double Area();
        double getRadius();


};

class Conus {
                double height;
                Circle C;
        public:
                Conus (double , double , double , double );
                ~Conus() {};
                double Volume();
                void setRadius(double );
        };

Conus::Conus(double h, double a, double b, double c)
        : C (a, b, c)
{
        height=h;
}
double Circle::Area() { return r*r*3.14; }
double Conus::Volume() { return C.Area()*height; }
double Circle::getRadius() { return r; }
void   Conus::setRadius(double t ) { C.getRadius()=t; }

int main() {
        double a=2.4, b=3.5, r=5.4, h=5.9;
        Circle Wre (a, b, r) ;
        Conus Konusi (h, a, b, r) ;
        cout << "Wris centris koordinatebia: " << a << " da " << b << ", radiusi: " << r
                << ". Wris fartobia :"  << Wre.Area() << endl;
        cout << "Konusis fudzis centris koordinatebia: " << a << " da " << b << ", radiusi: " << r
                <<endl<< "konusis moculobaa:  " << Konusi.Volume() << endl;
        Konusi.setRadius(r+3);
        cout << Konusi.Volume() << endl;

        _getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It will help you post questions which have a better chance of getting attention from the people that can help you.

Comment: I wanted to answer with "You're trying to assign a value to a function", but then i realized you can do that in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getRadius()` returns a copy of the object's radius, not a reference to it, so you can't use it for modification. So the following expression:

```
C.getRadius()=t;
```

attempts to modify a temporary copy, which isn't allowed. (The reason that its not allowed is that otherwise that code would compile but do nothing useful, giving a subtle bug rather than an easily identified compile error).

There are various options:

- return a reference, `double & getRadius();`
- add a `void setRadius(double);` function, and use that for modification
- make the radius public; there's little point in using accessors unless they're necessary to enforce invariants.

If you do want accessor functions, you should keep the existing `double getRadius()`, but declare it `const`. That will allow you to get, but not modify, the radius of a constant object.

Answer (score 2):

This is a not a correct assignment, you are attempting to modify a temporary copy of the `r` not `r` itself:

```
C.getRadius()=t;
```

One way to fix this would be to add this method to `Circle`:

```
void setRadius( double t ){ r = t ; }
```

and call like:

```
void   Conus::setRadius(double t ) { C.setRadius( t ); }
```

this is a great article [Understanding lvalues and rvalues in C and C++](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) and the first example is similar to the problem you were facing just now.

Comment: cant uccess Circle r from Conus class founction

Comment: @user2161119: if you want to be able to modify the radius of a `Circle` from other classes, you will need to provide a setter, like you did in `Conus`.

Comment: @Detheroc Correct, fixed my post accordingly